# Выбор OC для начинающего бэкенд-разработчика

Tags: linux, windows

Я начинающий веб-разработчик, учусь и пишу на php.
99% времени пользовался Windows.
Но сейчас стоит выбор Linux или Windows 10
Уважаемые гуру, можете объяснить какие преимущества использования Linux (я выбрал для себя Ubunru 16.04 гном) есть по сравнение с Windows 10.

Порог вхождение немного выше чем в вин, нужно думать и т.п

Но я готов полностью разобраться, только если оно того стоит.
про бесплатный софт и то что можно слепить все что хочешь я прекрасно понимаю.

Я прочитал много статей в интернете на эту тему, и почти везде вода водой, переливают пустое в порожнее.
Буду благодарен за конструктивные ответы.

Comment: Проблем-то: поставить и начать работать. Можно в виртуалке, можно рядом с основной ОС... Понравится - переходить,не понравится - и фиг с ним.

Comment: +1 к виртуалке, как освоитесь, сами поймете, к чему душа лежит. Дома я вообще имею десятку основной системой и работаю в виртуалке.

Comment: я уже поставил , есть ли весомые плюсы по сравнение с win . вот этот вопрос меня интересует. почему задал вопрос? чтоб сэкономить время  время на разбор палетов

Comment: @mydls1, плюсы -  это *слишком субъективно* и *зависит от кучи факторов*. Что касается меня,  то лет 10 уже  в виртуалке стоят какие-то винды "на всякий случай" и запускаются очень редко. Живу и работаю всей семьёй, включая котов и собак, под линуксом, и не жужжу. Но - см. первое предложение...

Comment: Почему я так щепетильно подошел к этому вопросу, т.к в каждой 10й вакансии моей сферы  написано - желательно знание linux

Comment: Ну так "знайте" раз надо, не понимаю я вашего нытья. Как будто это настолько непомерный труд - ОС освоить... А что программисты, знающие один язык и/или одно направление, нафиг никому не нужны, не смущает?

Comment: с чего вы взяли то это нытье?

Comment: Если в каждой десятой и вас это смущает, то берите остальные девять. А вообще - вам надо знать платформу, на которой ваши приложения бегают. Только это совсем не десктоп.

Comment: @mydls1, вопросы уровня "какую ОС выбрать", "какой язык изучать" и т.д. - нытьё по определению. Не-нытики не задают таких вопросов, а выбирают и изучают. Причём далеко не по одному экземпляру каждого вида :)

Comment: забавно, объективный ответ дан, а вопрос закрыт. ну, главное автор получил что хотел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

на самом деле, для разработчика, вопрос выбора операционной системы вовсе не так субъективен, как может показаться.

А если учитывать, что  [67%](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/operating_system/all) веб-серверов используют Unix, выбор становится еще менее субъективным и, очевидно, диктуется:

а) *требованиями рынка* для данной конкретной специальности

б) *техническими преимуществами* для данной конкретной специальности

Если вы точно собрались в бэкэнд - имеет смысл выбрать линукс, поскольку существует объективное преимущество: под юниксы гораздо проще, например, собрать какой-нибудь нестандартный модуль для php/python.

Как пример: https://github.com/Crack/runkit-windows , т.е. если вы не можете сбилдить модуль сами, вам придется довольствоваться теми сборками, которые кто-то для вас сделает.

Еще пример: [билды](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) python-модулей для Windows. Поскольку сейчас бэкэнд это зачастую не только выдача контента, но и data science, зависимость от таких билдов абсолютно недопустима (да и неудобна)

Под винду эти все проекты, как правило, можно забилдить - но придется изучать костыли - поставить компилятор от MS, добавить либ, поправить там-сям make-файлы, посмотреть, пропатчить что-нибудь, чтобы отстающий  - как правило - по совместимости компилятор MS, мог понять ваш код. А может быть, вместо MSVC взять mingw/cygwin и т.д. и т.п. Это хорошо для лампового летнего кодинга по вечерам, в кругу друзей, но это не вариант для серьезной разработки.

С выходом [слоя совместимости](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) с Linux в десятке это преимущество, **возможно** сойдет на нет, но тогда вы просто учите Linux, находясь в Windows. И кроме того, нужно посмотреть, легко ли профилировать/дебажить находясь в этом слое совместимости, работают ли там юниксовые *strace*  и другие *низкоуровневые* инструменты

кроме того, до недавних пор Windows не мог нормально работать с симлинками. Если в проекте используются симлинки - хана. Сейчас вот, говорят, стало лучше, но я не проверял.

и, конечно, я забыл о кастомных демонах. если вы попадете в контору, которая использует линукс на продакшене и которая пишет демонов на c/c++, к которым обращаются php/python/ruby/node.js то, с вероятностью 100%, они будут разрабатывать их *только* под линукс, под win вы их просто не соберете.

ну и да, опыт работы с линуксом пригодится, когда вы будете участвовать в деплое.

повторюсь - все это касается только разработки бэкэнда (слегка - андроида, поскольку андроид - это linux)

P.S. когда вы научитесь спокойно работать в терминале, у вас будут хостинги, ssh-доступы, горы виртуалок и т.д., вы всегда можете перейти на винду, но чисто педагогически - на период обучения - по крайней мере, я бы выбрал ту систему, с которой предстоит работать.

P.P.S. вынесу из комментов:
- "не настолько сложно компилировать" - это как раз очень субьективно. если у вас стоит php под MSVC - а это дефолтная сборка,  вам придется добыть MSVC и разбираться с ним.  Вы ставили когда-нибудь MSVC? под линукс сборка php выполняется очень просто.

На моей текущей работе достаточно серьезный и большой отдел машинного обучения и если мне придется ставить виртуалку для того, чтобы компилировать python-пакеты под линукс, производительность упадет. поэтому на работе - линукс.

Я не говорю, что win зло, просто если на рынке 67% серверов работают под Unix, а вы ищете работу в бэкэнде... ну. ОС - это всего лишь инструмент, сейчас мы его и выбираем. Если бы автор спросил про разработку игр для Xbox - я бы голосовал за винду.

"Далеко не все ими пользуются" и "я этим не пользуюсь, потому что у меня винда" - это не ответ на собеседовании, и это не решение для рабочих вопросов.

Какие еще могуть быть основания для выбора оси? Если вы ее для работы используете - берите то, что лучше подходит для работы, если для игр - берите то, что подходит для игр. Мы в данном случае говорим о работе, конкретно о бэкенде. На этот вопрос я и отвечал.

P.P.P.S некоторые пункты, из моего ответа справедливы и для OSX/MacOS. Хотя OSX - это Unix, но практические проблемы при работе с бэкэндом встречаются и там тоже. Как минимум, убогая - пока что - поддержка докера - через VirtualBox, как и на винде

P.P.P.P.S добавлю еще один пункт - если вы собираетесь работать в маленькой веб-студии - то смело идите с виндой. если google/yahoo/yandex/mail/rambler - смотрите [здесь](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=30545).

Новость старая, но, по моим наблюдениям, мало что изменилось - бэкенд разработка в коллективе в больших конторах в основном ведется под linux/bsd-osx.

С точки зрения именно UI/программ для разработки - никакой разницы между Windows/Linux  нет. Большинство серьезных программ, которые используются для бэкенд-дева кроссплатформенны - PhpStorm/NetBeans/Vim/Emacs. А в остальном - когда вы работаете, вы успеваете видеть только IDE/редактор, браузер с открытым проектом + стаковерфлоу, и терминал.  Если вы видите что-нибудь кроме терминала/редактора/браузера - значит, вы не работаете.

Comment: P.S. @mydls1 порог вхождения в десктопный линукс - такой же как для винды. просто учитесь побольше задач делать через терминал. терминал - ваш друг. а если будете работать с удаленными серверами, то и зачастую - единственный возможный интерфейс.  И не ставьте русскую версию, гуглить сообщения об ошибках будет гораздо тяжелей, да и язык не прокачается. вот вам в догонку https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/9b/fb/ff9bfbf6c2729431fd97d664078d28b7.jpg

Comment: @strangeqargo "Нестандартные модули" не настолько критичны, далеко не всеми используются, и их не настолько сложно компилировать (если они поддерживаются), чтобы на этом основании выбирать ось. Если для какого-нибудь руби одна "родная система", то для похапэ всё заметно лучше.

Comment: "*Если вы видите что-нибудь кроме терминала/редактора/браузера - значит, вы не работаете*" - [Инь Фу Во](http://forensics.ru/InFuWo.htm#c0111) же :-)

Comment: вот да. когда наши начинают вдруг от нечего делать выбирать дистриб, значит, им нечем заняться. Последний раз такое было с год назад. заканчивалось https://pp.vk.me/c636031/v636031528/8335/dcyZloIgsIk.jpg